# How to use a variable from a try block into the catch block

Tags: php, try-catch, undefined

I have this code:

```
    try {
        // Get a response from an API
        $apiBody = $this->api->get('Info')
            ->getBody();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        if ($e instanceof ConnectException) {
            // Set a flash error message
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('danger', 'Errore durante l\'importazione. URL non valido.');
            $wrongUrlNotification = new Notification();
            $wrongUrlNotification->setForUser($user)
                ->setMessage('Errore durante l\'importazione. URL non valido.');
            $this->em->persist($wrongUrlNotification);
        } else {
            // Set a flash error message
            $message = 'Errore durante l\'importazione. Il messaggio restituito dal sistema è il seguente: ' . $e->getMessage() . ' [CODICE: ' . $e->getCode() . ']';
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('danger', $message);
            $exceptionNotification = new Notification();
            $exceptionNotification->setForUser($user)
                ->setCreatedOn(new \DateTime())
                ->setCode(0)
                ->setMessage($message)
                ->setDebug($apiBody);
            $this->em->persist($exceptionNotification);
        }
    }
```

The problem is with the variable `$apiBody`.

As you can see, I give it a value in the `try` block. If an exception is thrown, I want to store in the database the string returned by the API, so I can debug it later and understand what causes the error.

**The problem is that PHPStorm tells me that `$apiBody` in the catch block isn't defined, and also in the database it is stored as a `null` value.**

I don't understand why... I have never dealt such a situation, but I think the variable is defined.

**What am I missing? How can I store the API's response body in the database if an exception is triggered?**

Comment: You can actually do this in php, the `$apiBody` variable is still available in the `catch` block, but if you want to make it correctly by scope, simply define the `$apiBody` variable before (outside) the `try` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception was thrown somewhere in `$this->api->get('Info')->getBody()`. It didn't even get to return a value, much less to assign that value to `$apiBody`. The variable *is* indeed not defined because an exception was thrown in the process of defining it.